# Microwave replacement

Tags: microwave-oven

I need to replace a microwave that used to be in the space shown below. I am not sure what kind of microwave should I put there or what kind of prep work I should do. I think the microwave that hangs onto a plate won't work here. Notice also that trim work around the opening is pretty rough, it used be covered by microwave surround kit. The space opening is 25"x15"x16".

[image: Microwave space]

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Buy a micro that fits. Go to microtrim.com or equivalent for the surround.

Comment: If the total opening is 30 inches, you may be able to remove the entire cabinet box and hang an above the range micro there.  If not you will just have to shop for a countertop micro that fits.

Comment: @RMDman that was my first thought too.  If the gap between the adjacent cabinets is 30", an OTR nuke would fit there well (door opening to the left would be best).  OP might have to relocate the outlet to the cabinet above, but that should be reasonably trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to shop for countertop microwaves that (a) fit the space, (b) do *not* require ventilation in the back or, if they require ventilation in the top, bottom or sides do not require more than you can provide here. What is *likely* to work best is models that are designed for in-cabinet mounting, which is often an option that includes a kit to (a) surround the front (solving your trim problem) and (b) lift the microwave up so that there can be sufficient ventilation underneath.

Sample search on Home Depot, first result is [Frigidaire Gallery](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FRIGIDAIRE-GALLERY-24-4375-in-Width-2-2-cu-ft-Stainless-Steel-1100-Watt-Built-In-Microwave-GMBS3068AF/320574931) which is available with various trim kits. Go to the specifications page (link is on the Home Depot product page) and it shows height 13-5/8" (OK), width 24-7/16" (OK), depth 19-5/8" (**NOT OK**). But more importantly, there is another page with the dimensions for the trim kits and it also has the "CABINET OR WALL CUTOUT" dimensions:

- Height 16-3/4" - 17"
- Width 24-3/4" - 25"
- Depth 20" Minimum

The 27" trim kit has overall dimensions of, you guessed it, 27" wide. Which would cover up the rough trim nicely.

So while this particular model won't work, those are the sorts of specifications you need to look at until you find one (hopefully) that matches.

A lot of appliances like this are designed for 20" - 23" depth because that's the standard "full depth" appliance size. Typical upper cabinets for dishes and stuff, but not for appliances, are 12" deep and there are some in-between sizes like you have. So it may be a little tough to find something to match the depth that you have.

An alternative is an ordinary countertop microwave oven. Which, provided it fits, will work just fine as long as the ventilation is OK. It just won't have the "built in" look.

Comment: Thank you mentioning ventilation, didn't consider that at first.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that fits will work, just follow the manufacturers clearance on sides, top and back.  Removing the trim will give you a larger space to work with.